# Benefits and drawbacks for CAAnimationGroup vs. CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: iphone, performance, optimization, core-animation, caanimation

I'm currently working on some core animation stuff for the iOS and really enjoying myself. This question is regarding the many different ways one can implement an animation. Say you would like to rotate a UIView a few times but with different timing functions for each animation cycle. To the best of my knowledge there are at least two different way of implementing this:

1. I either create a `CAAnimationGroup` and add the different `CABasicAnimation` objects to it. By controlling their `beginTime` property and setting different `CAMediaTimingFunction` on them I get the individual behavior I want.
2. The other option is to create a `CAKeyframeAnimation` and by adding different key values I can customize the different "frames" individually.

So my question is this: **Is there any advantage of using either one of these implementations?**

My follow up question: **If so, what method do you use for finding this out? In other words, how would I go about measuring the performance of an animation?**

Thank you in advance and best regards.

//Abeansits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the choice between the two is a semantic one:

- If I want to animate *one* object over *several* stages, I use a keyframe animation.
- If I want to animate *several* objects concurrently, I use an animation group (that can optionally consist of several keyframe animations if the animations of the single objects contain multiple stages).

Comment: Ok, seems to make sense. But do you have any ways of actually making sure that one method is not more efficient than the other? Since you are actually implementing the animation using different classes & interfaces there should be, at least a minor, difference in their performance. Or am I seeing this wrongly?

Comment: I don't know. But I would be surprised if the differences were in any way significant. In a low-level implementation, both should boil down to very similar code.